# Debugging .NET webservice: timeout

Tags: .net, web-services, iis

I am debuggig a .NET webservice hostet on an IIS.

When setting breakpoints etc. it's easy to hit a timeout, and the webserive will stop.

Is there an easy way to disable the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the IIS manager (inetmgr.exe), select your application pool, and disable `Ping`.

[Further reading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725836%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).